# Haskell \p -> not takeWhile

Tags: haskell

Let the following code in Haskell:

```
isPrime n

| n <= 1 = False
| n == 2 = True
| n == 3 = True
| even n = False
| otherwise = all (\p -> not $ divideBy p n) testingSlice

where

  testingNumbers = iterate (+ 2) 3

  testingSlice = takeWhile (\p -> square p <= n) testingNumbers
```

What does "\p -> square p <= n?"
          "all (\p -> not $ divideBy p n) testingSlice" mean?

What does "\p -> square p <= n?" mean?

How to translate in pseudo code?

Comment: Sounds an awful lot like homework, maybe add a few lines about what you did so far to understand what's going on in that snippet.

Comment: The problem is the following: By listing the first six prime numbers: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, and 13, we can see that the 6th prime is 13. What is the 10 001st prime number?

Answer (score 1):

```
\p -> square p <= n
```

It's an unnamed (anonymous) function that accepts variable *p*, squares it and compares result with *n*.

```
all (\p -> not $ divideBy p n) testingSlice
```

checks that anonymous function returns **true** value for each element in *testingSlice*.

Read about [lambdas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function).